# Trying to loop through multiple arrays and getting error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (44,1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

New to for loops and I cannot seem to get this one to work. I have multiple arrays that I want to run through my code. It works for individual arrays, but when I try to run it through a list of arrays it tries to join the arrays together.

Pandas looping, multiple attempts at looping in numpy.

## Min regret matrix

`for i in [a],[b],[c],[d],[e]:`

## sum columns and rows:

```
   suma0 = np.sum(a,axis=0)
   suma1 = np.sum(a,axis=1)
```

#find the minimum values for rows and columns:

```
   col_min=np.min(a)
   col_min0=data.min(0)
   row_min=np.min(a[:44])
   row_min0=data.min(1)
```

## difference or least regret between scenarios and policies:

```
   p = np.array(a)
   q = np.min(p,axis=0)
   r = np.min(p,axis=1)
   cidx = np.argmin(p,axis=0)
   ridx = np.argmin(p,axis=1)
   cdif = p-q
   rdif = p-r[:,None]
```

## find the sum of the rows and columns for the difference arrays:

```
   sumc = np.sum(cdif,axis=0)
   sumr = np.sum(rdif,axis=1)
   sumr1 = np.reshape(sumr,(44,1))
```

## append the scenario array with the column sums:

```
   sumcol = np.zeros((45,10))
   sumcol = np.append([cdif],[sumc])
   sumcol.shape = (45,10)
```

## rank columns:

```
   order0 = sumc.argsort()
   rank0 = order0.argsort()
   rankcol = np.zeros((46,10))
   rankcol = np.append([sumcol],[rank0])
   rankcol.shape = (46,10)
```

## append the policy array with row sums

```
   sumrow = np.zeros((44,11))
   sumrow = np.hstack((rdif,sumr1))
```

## rank rows

```
   order1 = sumr.argsort()
   rank1 = order1.argsort()
   rank1r = np.reshape(rank1,(44,1))
   rankrow = np.zeros((44,12))
   rankrow = np.hstack((sumrow,rank1r))
   print(sumrow)
   print(rankrow)
```

## Add row and column headers for least regret for df0:

```
   RCP = np.zeros((47,11))
   RCP = pd.DataFrame(rankcol, columns=column_names1, index=row_names1)
   print(RCP)
```

## Add row and column headers for least regret for df1:

```
   RCP1 = np.zeros((45,13))
   RCP1 = pd.DataFrame(rankrow, columns=column_names2, index=row_names2)
   print(RCP1)
```

## Export loops to CSV in output folder:

```
   filepath = os.path.join(output_path, 'out_'+str(index)+'.csv')
   RCP.to_csv(filepath)
   filepath = os.path.join(output_path, 'out1_'+str(index)+'.csv')
   RCP1.to_csv(filepath)
```

Comment: Try to make the question more focused, And show us clearly were the error occurs, And check the dype of the problem array.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, please highlight the input, expected output and error as this is a base case example.

```
x = np.random.randn(2)
x.shape = (2,)
```

and if we attempt for :

```
x.reshape(44,1)
```

The error we get is:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (44,1)
```

reason for this error is simple as we are trying to reshape an array of size 2 into 44 sized array. As per your error highlighted please check the dimension of the input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am starting with an array (44,10), but the for loop is trying to process all the arrays simultaneously leading to the wrong shape array being used as an input. Spyder spits out the following error: 
  File "C:/Users/aeav330/Desktop/python_scripts/dappy/dappy3_working.py", line 155, in <module>
    sumr1 = np.reshape(sumr,(44,1))>   ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (44,1). So I have some issue with the array shape from what I understand, but why then does it work as an independent run but not when I try to loop through a list?

Comment: Could you describe your problem in much detail so that I can replicate it. I cannot understand anything from your question